# The answer key says That option A and C is correct but how C ? Since the lines cannot intersect each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, vector-fields

The answer key says That option A and C is correct but how C ? Since the lines cannot intersect each other[image]

Comment: What does the square next to B mean.? Is this a 2D or a 3D drawing?

Comment: Yes, (c) can't be the answer.

Comment: @Hilmar, square next to B is showing the perpendicular line from point A to B

Answer (score 2):

Electric field *lines* cannot intersect. Electric field *vectors* do not extend through physical space (the "length" of an electric field vector doesn't have units of length, does it?) and the concept of "intersection" does not entirely make sense for them. The *drawings* of the vectors in (c) *happen* to intersect, but that means nothing physically. Physically, the vectors are entirely "contained" at the points A and B and you could easily make the drawings not intersect by just choosing a different scale.

The intersection point does have physical relevance as the point where you'd have to place the point charge. In (a), where the drawings don't intersect, you have to extend them into infinite lines and place a positive point charge at the intersection of those. In (c), the intersection point is already found for you and you can just place a negative charge there to reproduce the field at A and B. In (b) and (d) you can try placing a point charge at the intersection of the lines, but that doesn't work out (can you explain why?).

Comment: in option b I think since the distance between the charge and point B is less therefore the force should be more but it is not happening according to options so...